# Access object.variable in an array of objects

Tags: java

I need help with this piece of code.

```
public class ParkingLot {

static int MAX = 5;
static Car[] Slot = new Car[MAX];

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Slot[0] = new Car("1234", "White");
    Slot[1] = new Car("5678", "Black");

}

public static void Allot() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= Slot.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Slot.getNo);

    }
}
```

I am storing a `Car` Object in `Slot`. I wish to print/access the `No` and `Colour` of the car stored in slot. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if `car` has a public property, or a public getter method (this is preferable - `getNumber()` and `getColour()`), you can call them while iterating the array with the for-each loop:

```
for (Car car : slot) {
    System.out.println(car.getColour());
}
```

Note that I've lowercased `slot` - variable names in Java should be lowercase. I'd also advise for naming the array with plural name - i.e. `slots`.

Note also that the way of iteration provided by others is possible, but not recommended for the basic case of iterating the whole array. [Effective Java (Bloch)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) recommends using the foreach loop whenever possible.

Comment: It's "syntactic sugar" - the loop iterates over all elements of the `slot` array/collection. Generally, `slot` should implement `Iterable`, but this is also true for arrays.

Comment: Also, method names should be lowercased too.  The "Allot()" method should be renamed to "allot()"

Answer (score 1):

Using `[]` notation:

```
public static void Allot() {
    Car car;
    for (int i = 0; i <= Slot.length; i++) {
        // Get the car at this position in the array
        car = Slot[i];

        // Make sure it isn't null, since the array may not have
        // a full set of cars
        if (car != null) {
            // Use the car reference
            System.out.println(car.getNo());
        }
    }
}
```

(I assumed by the name that `getNo` was a method, not a property.)

E.g., `Slot[0]` gives you the first `Car`, from which you can access `Car`'s properties and methods, so `Slot[i]` gives you the car at the `i`th position. (In the above I used a temporary variable to store the car, but you can use `Slot[i].getNo()` directly, it doesn't matter. I just didn't want to repeat the array lookup, even through HotSpot [the Sun JVM] will optimize it out even if I do.)

Comment: In his case I would add a if( Slot[i] != null ).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being so late. I noticed something missing in the above answers, so here is the complete solution for the problem stated.

Here is the ParkingLot class with a call to Allot() method.

public class ParkingLot {

```
static int MAX = 5;
static Car[] Slot = new Car[MAX];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Slot[0] = new Car("1234", "White");
    Slot[1] = new Car("5678", "Black");

    Allot();

}

public static void Allot() {

    for (int i = 0; i < Slot.length; i++) {

        if (Slot[i] != null) {
            System.out.println(Slot[i].getNo()+" , "+Slot[i].getColor());
        }
    }
}
```

}

And the Car class with the getNo() and getColor() methods.

public class Car {

```
private String Number;
private String Color;

Car (String Number, String Color){
    this.Number = Number;
    this.Color = Color;

}

public String getNo(){
 return Number;   
}

public String getColor(){
    return Color;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
class Car{
    String number;
    String color;

    public Car(String number, String color) {
        this.number = number;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "number='" + number + '\'' +
                ", color='" + color + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

class Test{
    static int MAX = 5;
    static Car[] Slot = new Car[MAX];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Slot[0] = new Car("1234", "White");
        Slot[1] = new Car("5678", "Black");

        for (Car car : Slot)
            System.out.println(car);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create and access object array of objects simply like this

```
Object[] row={"xx","xcxcx"};

Object[] cotainer = {row,row,row};

for(int a=0;a<cotainer.length;a++){

    Object[] obj = (Object[])cotainer[a];

}
```