# How do I print/refernce Person #7?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I print/referrence Person # 7? thanks!

I have tried multiple things however I haven't been able to reference person #7.
I am new to arrays and this is due tomorrow so any help would be great. I looked at some tutorials on youtube but I just can't figure out what's wrong? The way the array is being re-defined isn't the same way as the examaples I have been seeing.

```
import java.text.*;           // to use Decimal Format

public class TwoD_ArrayDriver

{

   public static void main(String[] args)

   {

       DecimalFormat myFormat;

       // to get 2 decimals every time

       myFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");



       Person p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18, p19, p20, p21;

       p1 = new Person("Abby", "Arthur"); p2 = new Person("Bubba","Brown"); p3 = new Person("Chuckie", "Cheese"); p4 = new Person("Don", "Drysdale"); p5 = new Person("Ernie","Eastwood");

       p6 = new Person("Flo", "Fauntroy"); p7 = new Person("Gabby", "Giffords"); p8 = new Person("Hank","Hoover"); p9 = new Person("Indy", "Imhauf"); p10 = new Person("Jim","Jones");

       p11 = new Person("Ken", "Koopman"); p12 = new Person("Larry", "Lancelot"); p13 = new Person("Michael", "Moore" ); p14 = new Person("Nina","Nonesuch"); p15 = new Person("Oscar","OToole");

       p16 = new Person("Pat","Pompous"); p17 = new Person("Quincy","Quinton"); p18 = new Person("Ralph","Rancid"); p19 = new Person("Steven","Simpson"); p20 = new Person("Tim","Tinker");

       p21 = new Person("Uncle","Usher");

       Person[] allPersons = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18, p19, p20, p21};

       Person[] mondayAppts = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5};

       Person[] tuesdayAppts = {p6, p7, p8};

       Person[] wednesdayAppts = {p9, p10, p11, p12};

       Person[] thursdayAppts = {p13, p14, p15, p16, p17};

       Person[] fridayAppts = {p18, p19, p20, p21};



       //Task #1 Print the id, first name, and last name of Person #7, using tuesdayAppts

       int intToPrint = 0;

       String fNameToPrint = "unknown";

       String lNameToPrint = "unknown";

       System.out.println("Person #7 "+intToPrint+" "+fNameToPrint+" "+lNameToPrint);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access object.variable in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123086/access-object-variable-in-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: The oracle tutorial doesn't have an example like the one I posted. I get junk when I use tuesdayAppts[1 0]  for the first name that is Gabby.

Comment: never mind - got the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Since you're trying to access through `tuesdayAppts` as `Person[] tuesdayAppts = {p6, p7, p8};` the variable `p7`, you should do `tuesdayAppts[1]`, since it is in the second position of the array.

#### Example (output: `Person #2 BBB bbb`)

```
class Person {
    
    private static int idGen = 0;
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.id = ++Person.idGen;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person #" + this.id + " " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
    
}

class Example {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person a, b, c;
        a = new Person("AAA", "aaa");
        b = new Person("BBB", "bbb");
        c = new Person("CCC", "ccc");
        Person[] personArray = {a, b, c};
        System.out.println(personArray[1]);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the person class has accessors I think what your asking is how to pull the info from the existing array?

```
   int intToPrint = tuesdayAppts[1].getID();

   String fNameToPrint = tuesdayAppts[1].getFName();

   String lNameToPrint = tuesdayAppts[1].getLName();
```

That's with accessors...without would be more like.

```
   int intToPrint = tuesdayAppts[1].id;

   String fNameToPrint = tuesdayAppts[1].fName;

   String lNameToPrint = tuesdayAppts[1].lName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, but I already got the answer. However I'm trying to make the one dimensional array to a two dimensional. This is what I have so far but it's not working.   Any help is appreciate and there is a Person class.

```
//Task #2 Create a 2D array out of the 1D arrays
    Person [][] weeklyAppts = new Person [5][5];

    for (int row= 0; row < 5; row ++)  //days of week
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col ++) //persons 
        {
            weeklyAppts [row] [col] = ?????? <<- what do I put here
        }
    }
```